# KnockoutJS bindinghandler with childBindingContext - $data === $parent

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am currently writing a custom binding handler to form a control in our page.
This control generates its own viewmodel als a child of the main viewmodel, as to not alter the original viewmodel. (the controls' implementation is not a concern of the page)

**Code sample**
I've created an abstract example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdarn/

JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.subBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var actualValue = valueAccessor();

        ko.virtualElements.emptyNode(element);

        var subViewModel = {};
        subViewModel.subValue =
            new ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(actualValue) * 2);

        var childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(viewModel);
        ko.utils.extend(childBindingContext, subViewModel);

        var getDomNodesFromHtml = function(html) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = html;
            var elements = div.childNodes;
            var arr = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                arr.push(elements[i]);
            }
            return arr;
        };

        var html = '<p data-bind="text: subValue"></p>' +
            '<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 4)"></pre>';

        ko.virtualElements.setDomNodeChildren(element, getDomNodesFromHtml(html));
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childBindingContext, element);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.subBinding = true;

var mainViewModel = {
    value1: new ko.observable(100),
    value2: new ko.observable(200)
};
ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel, document.getElementById('main'));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <p>Main viewmodel:</p>
    <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 4)"></pre>

   <hr />

   <!-- ko subBinding: value2 -->
   <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

**Problem**
The *$data* that is available on the bindinghandlers' viewmodel is actually the parent (main) viewmodel. This seems to be odd behaviour, as other properties such as *subValue* are actually bound correctly. These properties are not present on the main viewmodel.

**Guesswork**
My guess is that the controlsDescendantBindings is only being returned after the binding occurs. As such, the main viewmodel seeps through. KO then favours the $data that is present on the mainviewmodel-context instead.

**Question**
*(considering my guess is right)*
Is there a proper way to create and bind a child viewmodel to a (virtual, in this case) bindinghandlers' own  controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sigh, major oversight.

I based my implementation on a documentation page at:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html

The updated code can be found at:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdarn/2/

**Changes:**

```
var childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(viewModel);
ko.utils.extend(childBindingContext, subViewModel);
```

becomes

```
var childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(subViewModel);
```

I misinterpreted the parameter that createChildContext accepts - this parameter is the viewModel on the context of the child.

--

HTML snippet of control becomes:

```
var html = '<p data-bind="text: subValue"></p>' +
        'data: <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 4)"></pre>' + 
        'parent: <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($parent), null, 4)"></pre>' +
        'root through parentcontext: <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($parentContext.$root), null, 4)"></pre>' +
        'root (not working): <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($root), null, 4)></pre>';
```

Comment: Four years later, and this has just caused a lightbulb moment and fixed my problem, thanks :) Wonder how many people have been thrown by that documentation?